# Configure git globally to always init submodules on git clone?

Tags: git

I am trying to find a way to have `git clone` also init all submodules.

I can't find any documentation on this, is this really not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible. See the docs for [`git config submodule.recurse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-submodulerecurse): `git clone` is explicitly **not supported**.

Comment: Thx for linking the documentation. I guess the reason to not support this for git clone is just because it would be too simple and its more fun to annoy people? ;-) Ah well, it's what it is then..